# JQuery .each function

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of images on my ASP.NET page like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Image image = new Image();
    image.ID = "UpdateStatus";
    image.CssClass = "imageCss";
    image.ImageUrl = "Bump.GIF";
    this.Controls.Add(image);
}
```

I want to loop through each image.

Why does this not work? i.e. "Function 1" is outputted but "Function 2" is not

```
$(document.body).click(function () {
    console.log('Function 1');

    $('imageCss').each(function(){
        console.log('Function 2');
    });
});
```

Why does this not work? i.e. "Function 1" is outputted and "Function 2" outputted ONCE. Why not 3 times?

```
$(document.body).click(function () {
    console.log('Function 1');

    $(''#UpdateStatus'').each(function(){
        console.log('Function 2');
    });
});
```

This works fine BUT i cannot access 'this', it is NULL. I need to be able to reference the current image.

```
$(document.body).click(function () {
    console.log('Function 1');

    $.each('#UpdateStatus', function() { //Or when I use 'imageCss'
        console.log('Function 2');        
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(1) Your jQuery call `$('imageCss')` isn't a valid selector. You need to prefix the classname with '.' to denote that you want to select elements with the class "imageCss":

`$('.imageCss')`

(2) IDs must be unique. When you set Control.ID = "foo" on the server in ASP.NET, that is setting the *server-side* ID of the control. The client-side ID generated in the HTML will be a unique, long, ugly string like `ctl00_ctl01_pnlMain_foo1`. Your best option is to use class selectors. You can apply multiple classes to a single element by using a space to separate them:

```
myImage.CssClass = "image otherclass";
```

Both `$('.image')` and `$('.otherclass')` will correctly select the element.

(3) `this` does not exist because of [**closures**](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html). Functions are executed in the context of the object that invokes the function, so `this` will be that object.

Or, in your case it doesn't really look like your function is executing within the context of any object, so I'm not sure what you're expecting `this` to be.

Answer (score 0):

to reference the current image do something like:

```
$.each('#UpdateStatus', function(i, val) {
    console.log('Function 2');        
    console.log(val);
});
```